# Populate dropdownlist with a class

Tags: class, drop-down-menu, populate

I want to create a "package program" for address part of my projects. I need it in almost every project so i wanted to make it easier.

So i decided to create a class to load city names to a dropdownlist. Here i coded:

```
public class Address
{
    string connStr = "Data Source...";

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Address(int ID, string Name)
    {
        this.id = ID;
        this.name = Name;
    }

    public List<Address> LoadCities()
    {
        List<Address> cities = new List<Address>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select x,y from ...", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Address city = new Address(rdr.GetInt32(0), rdr.GetString(1));
            cities.Add(city);
        }
        con.Close();
        return cities;
    }
}
```

This is my package program. I added this as a reference to my project. And tried to populate my dropdownlist as follows:

```
        List<Address> cities = ???

        ddlCity.DataTextField = "x";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "y";
        ddlCity.DataSource = cities;
        ddlCity.DataBind();
```

At ??? position i just wanted to code like this: List cities = Address.Loadcities();

So, i have a mistake here and i couldnt get it. Because i am new at "class" works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static List<Address> LoadCities()
```

You need the function on that class to be static.

Then you just do:

```
List<Address> cities = Address.LoadCities();
```

Here's some documentation for those times when you can't sleep:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: Thank u. That was all i need. Thank u again (for the link too) :)